Can a foreign key be used as the primary key of another table in a one to many relationship on ERD?
Can someone check if my ERD is correct?
erd
The main concern for me is in the transaction to game publisher connection.
I made the game_id from the GAME table a foreign key of the table GAME PUBLISHER. Then I made the game_id from the GAME PUBLISHER a foreign key to the TRANSACTION table. Is that allowed? and if not is there an alternative? Asnwers would be greatly appreaciated Thanks!

The structure of the tables (PKs and FKs in particular) does not satisfy (does not match) the relationships as drawn.  But it's not possible to suggest fixes and solutions unless you state the requirements (in English): what each table is supposed to represent and how they are supposed to be related (to be able to answer questions like e.g. may a Game have many Publishers? or, aren't Transactions per Game as opposed to per Publisher? etc.).
